# Pyspark command in terminal launches Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have run into an issue with spark-submit , throws an error is not a Jupyter Command i.e, pyspark launches a web ui instead of pyspark shell

Background info:

1. Installed Scala , Spark using brew on MAC
2. Installed Conda Python 3.5
3. Spark commands work on Jupyter Notebook
4. 'pyspark' on terminal launches notebook instead of shell

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue. I have set `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` as `python3 ` and have commented out `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS` also, not much help. Running `pyspark` launches a notebook for me!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON variable is set to start ipython/jupyter automatically (probably as intended.)  Run `unset PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` and then try pyspark again.

If you wish this to be the default, you'll probably need to modify your profile scripts.

Comment: Thanks a ton ! Even though it didn't launch the shell explicitly on the terminal I am able to use 'spark-submit'